# Cant run vertx module for eclipse project on windows 7

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, vert.x

I can't run vertx module for eclipse project on windows 7

I have followed the instructions here: http://vertx.io/gradle_dev.html

1. download the template https://github.com/vert-x/vertx-gradle-template
2. run the tests

   `cd vertx-gradle-template-master`

   `gradlew.bat test`

   `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`
3. setup the ide

   `gradlew.bat eclipse`

   `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`
4. trying to run module

   `gradlew.bat runMod`

I got this:

```
:collectDeps UP-TO-DATE
:runMod
Module directory build\mods\com.mycompany~my-module~1.0.0-final already exists. Creating properties on demand (a.k.a. dynamic properties) has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please read http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html for information
on the replacement for dynamic properties.
Deprecated dynamic property: "args" on "task ':runMod'", value: "[runmod, com.mycompany...".

Building 50% > :runMod
```

What I should do with this? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you got everything working!

The dev guide [0] provides the extra information you need. According to it, Gradle swallows INFO-level messages from the program.  If you do it again with '-i', then you will see the missing output that actually indicates things are working as expected.

Here's what I see when I run `./gradlew runmod -i` (note that case doesn't matter, this works same as using 'runMod'), where you can see the log message from the PingVerticle class indicating it's waiting for ping messages:

```
...Same output as from the question...
PingVerticle started
Succeeded in deploying module
> Building 50% > :runMod
```

Unfortunately, the documentation is sorely lacking and the PingVerticle will just sit there indefinitely until you actually send a ping message yourself.

[0] http://vertx.io/dev_guide.html